# Python list of dictionaries aggregate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-structures

Here is an example input:

```
[{'name':'susan', 'wins': 1, 'team': 'team1'}
{'name':'jack', 'wins':1, 'team':'team2'}
{'name':'susan', 'wins':1, 'team':'team1'}]
```

Desired output

```
[{'name':'susan', 'wins':2, 'team': 'team1'}
{'name':'jack', 'wins':1, 'team':'team2'}]
```

I have lots of the dictionaries and want to only add, the 'win' value, based on the 'name' value,
and keep the 'team' values

I've tried to use `Counter`, but the result was

```
{'name':'all the names added toghther',
 'wins': 'all the wins added toghther'
}
```

I was able to use `defaultdict` which seemed to work

```
result = defaultdict(int)
```

```
for d in data:
  result[d['name']] += d['wins'])
```

but the results was something like

```
{'susan': 2, 'jack':1}
```

Here it added the values correctly but didn't keep the 'team' key

I guess I'm confused about defaultdict and how it works.

any help very appreciated.

Comment: How is your data layout for the fist input - eg. list of `dict` or other kind?

Comment: What you want here?

Comment: @DanielHao the input is a list of dictionaries, some have the same name, those I want to add the values, but keep each unique name, and in the end I would like the 'team' key to still be present, the result should be another list of dicts, but with the 'win' value summed

Answer (score 4):

Did you consider using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd


dicts = [
    {'name':'susan', 'wins': 1, 'team': 'team1'},
    {'name':'jack', 'wins':1, 'team':'team2'},
    {'name':'susan', 'wins':1, 'team':'team1'},
]
agg_by = ["name", "team"]

df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
df = df.groupby(agg_by)["wins"].apply(sum)

df = df.reset_index()
aggregated_dict = df.to_dict("records")
```

Comment: Panda has built-in support - that's nice and convenient..

Comment: well that was ridiculously easy, thank you!

Comment: yep, that's python:)

Comment: Just a side note -  the `r` is going to be deprecated...  Got this message: FutureWarning: Using short name for 'orient' is deprecated. Only the options: ('dict', list, 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index') will be used in a future version. Use one of the above to silence this warning.

Comment: thats true, sry, fixed!